# OPENUI5 \ SAPUI5 bug?

Tags: css, html, sapui5, sap-fiori

I tried to develop ui table control with multi select option.
The label of each column is sap.m.Text:

[image]

But when i re size the column width, parts from the label text are hide:

[image]

It's all because of the "sapUiSizeCozy" class for the multi select option (the checkbox)

When i don't use this "sapUiSizeCozy" class the label text will be OK and wrapped, but, there will no be checkboxex:

[image]

I add this css class to the sap.m.Page control
Any help?
I need that the label will wrapped + the checkbox in each row

Thanks!

Edit:
Please see an example in:
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rpgie7BWIy96lyCvolJD)

You can in view.xml file remove the:

```
class="sapUiSizeCozy"
```

And re size the Product Name" column to see that the column is wrapping

Comment: @ShayZambrovski As this issue is no longer reproducible (seems to have been fixed by the framework), could you vote to close this question? Click on _flag_ and choose _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sapUiSizeCozy sets a fixed height to the table header. The label text is then verticaly centered by sapUiSizeCozy by setting lineheight to the height of the header.

This results in the effect that the label is wrapped but the second row is cut of by the fixed header height.

You can fix that with the following css (see [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YBbFYrbUixICeTigKVih?p=preview)):

```html
<html:style>
  .sapUiSizeCozy .sapUiTable .sapUiTableColCell>* span{ 
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  }
</html:style>
```